# mysqldump: insufficient privileges to show create function 'function name'

Tags: mysql

I want to dump my database with function and procedure in mysql workbench. I could dump my DB without functions and procedures.but when I try to export the data with procedures, it showed me the error like:

> "mysqldump:user has insufficient privileges to show create function function name"

Comment: Try to dump it as a root user with all privilages

Comment: actually i could not do it with terminal. becos i have another problem. when I run mysql -u root -p, it showed me the error like 'access denied for user root@localhost'. so that i tried in workbench

Answer (score 37):

To dump a database also with stored procedures, you must grant SELECT rights to mysql.proc:

Execute this statement once as root:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc to 'your-mysqldump-user';
```

Replace *your-mysqldump-user* with the real username.

<strike>Then flush the privileges:</strike>

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Now you should be able to dump the database including stored procedures with your mysqldump-user.

UPDATE: as @Michael pointed out in the comments, FLUSH PRIVILEGES isn't nesseccary in this case

Comment: for a grant statement you don't need to flush privileges. only if you manipulate the privileges tables in the db with updates

Comment: The table mysq.proc no longer exists in mysql 8.

Comment: Does anyone know what should be done in MySQL 8.0 for a similar problem?

Comment: This no longer works, I asked (and got an answer) about the solution for this in MySQL 8 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105092/what-are-the-apropriate-permissions-for-mysqldump-8-routines