# What are the apropriate permissions for MySQL(dump) 8 --routines

Tags: mysql

When using `mysqldump` with a non-root user and the `--routines` flag, I get the following error message:

```
mysqldump: <user> has insufficient privileges to SHOW CREATE FUNCTION `<function name>`!
```

Additionally, `mysqldump` hints towards the problem:

```
-- insufficient privileges to SHOW CREATE FUNCTION `<function name>`
-- does <user> have permissions on mysql.proc?
```

This seems as clear cut as it gets, until I actually tried it and found out that `mysql.proc` was deprecated in MySQL 8. I was not able to find the new equivalent, nor could I find out why `mysqldump` even suggests a deprecated table in the first place. Both my `mysqld` as well as my `mysqldump` are version 8.0.21.

Using `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO <user>` 'solves' the issue and allows the user to export the function, but obviously that is not a practical solution for a production system.

So what is the new `GRANT` or setting that specifically allows a user to `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION` (on a function that isn't theirs) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GRANT SHOW_ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_show-routine